# how to make python threading faster (camera imaging & screen capturing)

Tags: python, multithreading, image, opencv, capture

I'm a new guy using python, and try to capture screen (win32gui) and camera images (opencv) with threads. But my code is not fast enough to capture the images.
When the script works on a single thread, the frame rate is OK (about 30fps). But the frame rate drops to 10fps when two threads start. What can I do to improve the frame rate to 30 fps?
My laptop is win 64, i7-5500U, RAM 32GB, python 2.7 (32 bits). The camera is logical webcam C905.

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
import cv2
import os
import datetime, time
import threading


def screen_capture(saveDC, mfcDC, w, h):
    SaveDirectory = r'C:\Users\Desktop\1'
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = time.time()

    while (end_time - start_time < 8):
        saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), mfcDC, (300, 400), win32con.SRCCOPY)
        bmpname = os.path.join(SaveDirectory, str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':', '-') + '.bmp')
        saveBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(saveDC, bmpname)
        end_time = time.time()

def camera_image(cap):
    dirname = 'C:/Users/Desktop/2'
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = time.time()

    while(end_time - start_time < 8):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':', '-')
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dirname, timestamp + ".jpg"), frame)
        end_time = time.time()


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret = cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960)  # width
cap.set(4, 720)  # Height
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 90)  # Frame rate

w = 1500
h = 900
hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

t1 = threading.Thread(name=camera_image, target=camera_image, args=(cap,))
t2 = threading.Thread(name=screen_capture, target=screen_capture, args=(saveDC, mfcDC, w, h,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Use the `multiprocessing` module instead to avoid conflicts involving the GIL

Comment: Adding to @ppperry, use multiprocessing with processes to avoid the Global Interpreter Lockin (GIL) which dosent allow you to run in parallel. The negative side is that you have to deal with concurrence problems. Using processes let you run in a real parallel way.

Comment: Python 2.7 in 2016 ?

Comment: @ppperry Thanks for your suggestion. I can try it.

Comment: @Hamlett Thanks. My hope is to synchronize two signals. If processes can do that work. That is great.

Comment: @JulienPalard Do you mean python 3.x can be faster? I thought 2.x can be good enough for my use.

Comment: @Charlesliu it will be good enought, true, but if you are starting a new project just do it in python 3.x, Python 2.7 has an end date: http://pythonclock.org/. BTW, what do you mean with synchronize two signals? Take a look at [blinker](https://pythonhosted.org/blinker/), just to see if what you are looking for. In multiprocessing you have a set of [synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives)

Comment: @Hamlett Thanks a lot for your suggestions.